# Autoencoder algorithm and principle and why encoder part is blurry

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

Trying to understand the autoencoders, I am looking for an algorithm of an autoencodeur and the principle of autoencoders function, mathematical formulas ..

I'm currently working on autoencoders and trying to take the encoder output the compressed data and i'm not sure if that's the good result

i'm i in the right way?

[image: output of ecoder]

code :

```
nput_img = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
encoder_mode = Model(input_img, encoded)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
...
autoencoder.fit
...
...
encoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(X_test)

plt.imshow(encoded_imgs[i])
```

is it the encoded input it must be a the characteristic and compressed data ?

Answer (score 0):

Autoencoders are used to encode the main features of the input data. You can think of it as a feature extractor. The result will be blurred because there is data loss when you encode. The principle is to represent the input with less data.

Your input data is `64x64x3 = 12288` pixels. And your encoded is `8x8x64 = 4096`. Which is 1/3 of the input data.

Encoded size calculation:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3)) # 64x64x3

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img) # 64x64x32
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x) # 32x32x32
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x) # 32x32x64
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x) # 16x16x64
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x) # 16x16x64

encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x) # 8x8x64
```

So you are reconstructing the original image from 33% of its data. It is quite impressive and of course there will be a little blur.